# How to adjust application-specific volume in Lubuntu?

Tags: sound, lubuntu, lxde

I'm now using Lubuntu(LXDE + OpenBox), but I really miss the omnipotent control over audio in Ubuntu, like the screenshot below:

[image: ubuntu sound control]

I just want to adjust application-specific volume, e.g., that of  VirtualBox(since adjusting volume in guest OS doesn't work though audio drivers are installed), how can I achieve this?

I tried `Alsamixergui` and `pavucontrol(PulseAudio Volume Control)`, but they don't offer such fine-grained controls.